# Find minimum of $\frac x {x^2+1} + \frac y{y^2+1} + \frac z{z^2+1}$

Tags: inequality

Find ***minimum*** of $$M=\frac x {x^2+1} + \frac y{y^2+1} +  \frac z{z^2+1}$$
where $x,y,z \in \mathbb R\wedge x+y+z=xy+yz+xz$

---

I tried:
$$M=\sum \frac 1{x+\frac {1}{x}}\ge \frac 9{\sum{x+\frac 1x}}.$$
$$\text{So, we need to find maximum of } \sum x+ \frac 1x=x+y+z+\frac {x+y+z}{xyz}$$
but how ?

Comment: Rational functions are $C^\infty$, so a brute force but not elegant way is to check for critical points by differentiating. This should be your last resort.

Comment: Differentiate?. This involves a simple elementary math.

Comment: Laplace multiplier should be easier to do.

Comment: Clearly, $x = y = z = 0$ satisfies the hypotheses and $M = 0$. The maximum of $\sum x + 1/x$ will lead you nowhere.

Comment: One can get $M=-.054$ or so using $t,t,u$.

Comment: If we are trying individual numbers, why not $-1,-1,1$?

Comment: @Yimin did you mean _Lagrange_ multipliers?

Comment: @Kaster Yes, I mean that...Sorry about the typo. XD

Comment: Is there any reason that OP's condition $x,y,z > 0$ was altered with $x,y,z \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: @Kaster I think there is no other condition for $x,y,z$, since you can see there is a natural low bound for the problem, when $x=y=z = -1$, but this does not fit the equality.

Answer (score 2):

If $x=y=-1$ and $z=1$ we get a value $-\frac{1}{2}$ and it remains to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{x^2+1}\geq-\frac{1}{2}$$ or
$$(x+y+z+xyz)^2+(x+y+z+1)^2+\sum_{cyc}(x-yz)^2\geq0$$
and we are done!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question, the minimum seems to be $-\frac{1}{2}$ with $x=1$,$y=-1$ and  $z=-1$.